# Replacing original EventEmitter with custom one

Tags: javascript, node.js, monkeypatching, eventemitter

Consider I want to use `EventEmitter2`, or some implementation of `EventEmitter` of my own. However, if I just do `EventEmitter = MyEventEmitter`, it only helps for explicit inheritance that happens after this declaration, but obviously won't change existing objects inheriting from builtin `EventEmitter`, and is limited to scope of module.

Can I take advantage of alternative `EventEmitter`s when using builtin objects? I can think of just descending prototype chain of any particular object, and if prototype appears to be instance of `EventEmitter`, replace it with my own, but isn't there more elegant way?

Comment: i don't know if this is correct but you shouldn't do that, i believe many core modules or 3rd party modules that use events rely on build-in `EventEmitter` you might break something.. whats is wrong with `var EventEmitter2 = ..` ?

Comment: What's the point of custom `EventEmitter`, if you can't use it anywhere? E.g. this brings incosistence — few (yours) objects use custom `EventEmitter` capable of, say, `.many` or event wildcards, and builtin objects use builtin `EventEmitter` that does not expect to deal with `.many`. So, is there any point in custom EventEmitters, if you are the only to use them with your custom API, and others will just stick to good old `on` and `emit`?

Comment: Here — http://stackoverflow.com/q/12150540/472695 — in related question the solution is to extend builtin `EventEmitter`'s prototype. But this restricts one to use underlying vanilla implementation, so you have no control about precise structures behind handlers, you cannot, say, implement `on('*')`, because standard `EventEmitter` does not expose convenient ways to do this. I'm fully okay with responsibility to keep it fully backward-compatible in best traditions of duck typing.