# Combine multiple listening methods into one node.js

Tags: node.js, methods, sass

I have a node module that watches for events.

```
sassWatcher
    .on('init', () => sasstoCSS(prod, config, sassPath))
    .on('update', () => sasstoCSS(prod, config, sassPath))
```

I'd make it one line. So it's like:

```
sassWatcher
        .on('init' || 'update', () => sasstoCSS(prod, config, sassPath))
```

Is there a way to do this in Node.js, regardless of the library? Putting the two events in an array doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150540/javascript-eventemitter-multiple-events-once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docs for `EventEmitter`, you can see there is no built-in way of passing multiple event strings with a single handler.

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

However, if you are just trying to stay [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), there is a way you can refactor your code it is less repetitive.

```
['init', 'update'].forEach(event => {
    sassWatcher.on(event, () => sasstoCSS(prod, config, sassPath))
})
```